# Converting strings to floats in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How to covert a DataFrame column containing strings and `NaN` values to floats. And there is another column whose values are strings and floats; how to convert this entire column to floats.

Comment: DO NOT USE **`convert_objects`**. It is deprecated. Use `to_numeric` or `astype` instead

Answer (score 82):

> **NOTE:** `pd.convert_objects` has now been deprecated. You should use `pd.Series.astype(float)` or `pd.to_numeric` as described in other
>   answers.

This is available in 0.11. Forces conversion (or set's to nan)
This will work even when `astype` will fail; its also series by series
so it won't convert say a complete string column

```
In [10]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = Series(['1.0','1']), B = Series(['1.0','foo'])))

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
     A    B
0  1.0  1.0
1    1  foo

In [12]: df.dtypes
Out[12]: 
A    object
B    object
dtype: object

In [13]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[13]: 
   A   B
0  1   1
1  1 NaN

In [14]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes
Out[14]: 
A    float64
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Please note that this does not work for columns (at leadt multiindex), works just for values in the dataframe

Comment: I had to use set_levels to convert string to float

Comment: then you are doing something wrong. converting string to float is an explicty user action.

Comment: `df['ColumnName'] = df['ColumnName'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` You can convert just a single column.

Comment: this is now pd.to_numeric(col) in newer versions

Comment: convert_objects is deprecated in newer pandas.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_numeric.

Comment: With pandas 0.22.0 `FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  To re-infer data dtypes for object columns, use Series.infer_objects()
For all other conversions use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.`

Answer (score 78):

You can try `df.column_name = df.column_name.astype(float)`. As for the `NaN` values, you need to specify how they should be converted, but you can use the `.fillna` method to do it.

*Example:*

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
     a    b
0  0.1  0.2
1  NaN  0.3
2  0.4  0.5

In [13]: df.a.values
Out[13]: array(['0.1', nan, '0.4'], dtype=object)

In [14]: df.a = df.a.astype(float).fillna(0.0)

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
     a    b
0  0.1  0.2
1  0.0  0.3
2  0.4  0.5

In [16]: df.a.values
Out[16]: array([ 0.1,  0. ,  0.4])
```

Answer (score 63):

In a newer version of pandas (0.17 and up), you can use [to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) function. It allows you to convert the whole dataframe or just individual columns. It also gives you an ability to select how to treat stuff that can't be converted to numeric values:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['1.0', '2', -3])
pd.to_numeric(s)
s = pd.Series(['apple', '1.0', '2', -3])
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='ignore')
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: To apply `pd.to_numeric` to a `DataFrame`, one can use `df.apply(pd.to_numeric)` as [explained in detail in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844867/604687).

Answer (score 37):

```
df['MyColumnName'] = df['MyColumnName'].astype('float64')
```

Comment: This does not work when converting from a String to a Float: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'date'`

Comment: @Jack do you know the workaround here? I'm running into this exact issue converting string to float.

Comment: @Hatt i am facing the same issue. did you find the solution for it?

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure but you seem to mix up date format and float.

# convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

Answer (score 14):

you have to replace empty strings ('') with np.nan before converting to float. ie:

```
df['a']=df.a.replace('',np.nan).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df['a'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
                            GHI             Temp  Power Day_Type
2016-03-15 06:00:00 -7.99999952505459e-7    18.3    0   NaN
2016-03-15 06:01:00 -7.99999952505459e-7    18.2    0   NaN
2016-03-15 06:02:00 -7.99999952505459e-7    18.3    0   NaN
2016-03-15 06:03:00 -7.99999952505459e-7    18.3    0   NaN
2016-03-15 06:04:00 -7.99999952505459e-7    18.3    0   NaN
```

but if this is all string values...as was in my case...
Convert the desired columns to floats:

```
df_inv_29['GHI'] = df_inv_29.GHI.astype(float)
df_inv_29['Temp'] = df_inv_29.Temp.astype(float)
df_inv_29['Power'] = df_inv_29.Power.astype(float)
```

Your dataframe will now have float values :-)