# Importing a table into pandas and specifying the data type with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the read_table command in pandas/Python to import a tab-delimited text file.

`q_data_1 = pd.read_table('data.txt', skiprows=6, dtype={'numbers': np.float64})`

...but get

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Without the dtype parameter, the column is imported as an 'object' dtype.

The 'numbers' column I think has missing data which trips up the import. How do I ignore these values?

EDIT (25-May-13): Any idea how to do this with columns that contain (i) time (e.g. '00:03:06') (ii) date (e.g. '2002-03-11') and percentages ('32.81%')? All of which convert to objects. (I have edited Q to reflect) (iv) numbers with commas (e.g. '10,982') to convert them to appropriate dtype?

Comment: Does it not get this dtype without you specifying?

Comment: Nope - it imports the whole column as object

Comment: What is in 'numbers' which isn't a float? And how do you want it to be?

Comment: What does 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype' - does it mean it cannot convert one of the numbers into a float?

Comment: Well, what happens without it? Is the column name exactly 'numbers' ?

Comment: Yep just checked, but the column has numbers with commas

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729483/converting-strings-to-floats-in-a-dataframe, you should prob just read it in and convert after (as I assume your separator in your file is NOT a comma)

Comment: Thanks for that very helpful - whats the best way of converting comma separated integers (e.g. 1,000) into integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've read in the DataFrame (without restricting dtype) you can then convert it (using [technique from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th)) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
df = pd.DataFrame([['1,002.01'], ['300,000,000.1'], ['10']], columns=['numbers'])

In [4]: df['numbers']
Out[4]:
0         1,002.01
1    300,000,000.1
2               10
Name: numbers, dtype: object

In [5]: df['numbers'].apply(locale.atof)
Out[5]:
0    1.002010e+03
1    3.000000e+08
2    1.000000e+01
Name: numbers, dtype: float64

In[6]: df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].apply(locale.atof)
```

Comment: BTW any idea how to do the same thing with a columns that contain (i) time (e.g. '00:03:06') (ii) date (e.g. '2002-03-11') and percentages ('32.81%')? All of which convert to objects. (I have edited Q to reflect)

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question, but rather ask a new one :). It's essentially the same trick in both cases (just define a function which does it to a single string and then apply it the column).

Comment: Okay will do. Is this the efficient way of doing it? As I am using Pandas because it efficiently handles large data sets using essentially C-libraries.

Comment: It's a good question, but certainly my advice is use this one and see if it is efficient enough, I think it will be reasonably efficient. There is a converters argument to read_csv which could be worth investigating...

Comment: Thanks for this appreciate you're help. Might be worth asking as a separate question ;)

Comment: Heavy use of the `%timeit` helper is always recommended :)