# Pandas Dataframe Plotting with uneven index values creates skewed graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe that consists of several experimental runs with different 'x-scales' to zero-in on a particular modelled behaviour, i.e.

- Exp1: xs = np.linspace(0.005,0.75,10)
- Exp2: xs = np.linspace(0.015,0.035,20)

Combining these into a single dataframe for processing is as simple as a `pd.concat` but my difficulty is in plotting results.

```
ax=v.plot(
figsize=(10,13),kind='line',
secondary_y='average_rx_delay',
logy=True,
title="Performance Comparison of Varying Packet Period Rates \n(counts on left, seconds on right)"
)
#ax.set_xlabel('Packet Emmission rate (per second)')
ax.set_ylabel('Packet Count')
```

[image]

As you can see, the data frame index is being used as the 'series title' you could say, but it's not being numerically assessed, leading to uneven and skewed lines.

It's slightly easier to see *why* this is happening if you plot it bar-wise

[image: bar plots of the problem]

What I'm looking for is something like the below but as lines.

[image: linearised scatter graph]

Which was generated lazily going the long way

```
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.scatter(list(v.index),
     v.collisions, c='r')
ax1.scatter(list(v.index),
     v.tx_counts, c='b')
ax1.scatter(list(v.index),
     v.rx_counts, c='g')
ax1.scatter(list(v.index),
     v.enqueued, c='y')
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.scatter(list(v.index),
     v.average_rx_delay, c='c')
```

Basically, I want line plots to take the `v.index` as the x-axis value but stick to being actual numbers!

I've tried adding `x=v.index` to the `plot` call, as well as adding the index as another column and tried using the new column in the same manner but that's been no joy.

Any magical ideas or should I just start going the long untidy DIY way?

**Update**

As per @ajean's question, this is what a selection of the data looks like. Note that `PER` is the 'added in again' index column for the `x=v.PER` attempt mentioned above, but it's correctly discarded by the main `.plot` anyway.

[image: dataframe screenshot]

Comment: I'm slightly confused, what does `v.index` look like?  You indicate that it's being used as "series names" but it looks to me like those are columns.  Where do your two x-scales live in the DataFrame?

Comment: @ajean updated to include dataview. 

Basically when plotting with the DataFrame, it looks like it's ignoring the idea that the indexes might be numerical instead of simply categorical. Long story short, I'm looking for 'straight' lines with a bit more detail between 0.015 and 0.035 because that's where all the interesting stuff is happening.

Comment: Hmmm.  Your first plot example doesn't use `x=v.PER`, so it should discard that, which is fine.  Perhaps check what kind of index you have (i.e. make sure it's a `Float64Index` or if it's something that would translate to categorical)?  I feel like `plot()` should just work, unless you've hit a bug in pandas. If you post a copy-pasteable piece of the dataframe I can test it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your index is used as a categorial input. You can try df.column_name = df.column_name.astype(float). I have based this answer on [Converting strings to floats in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729483/converting-strings-to-floats-in-a-dataframe). If you want lines instead of points, then you should use plot instead of scatter.