# pandas.DataFrame.plot creates incorrect plots with twin axis and uneven index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Please consider the two plots generated by the following script. The line plot is incorrectly positioned in `fig2`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0x5eed)

arr1 = np.random.randint(5, 10, 4)
arr2 = np.random.randint(15, 20, 4)
idx = [1, 3, 4, 5]
kwargs = {'marker': 'o', 'color': 'C1'}

fig1, ax11 = plt.subplots()
ax12 = ax11.twinx()
ax11.bar(idx, arr1)
ax12.plot(idx, arr2, **kwargs)
fig1.savefig('fig1.png')

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': arr1, 'bar': arr2}, index=idx)
fig2, ax21 = plt.subplots()
ax22 = ax21.twinx()
df['foo'].plot.bar(ax=ax21)
df['bar'].plot.line(ax=ax22, **kwargs)
fig2.savefig('fig2.png')
```

`fig1` (expected):

[image: fig1]

`fig2` (unexpected):

[image: fig2]

After some investigation, I found the following conditions to reproduce this problem.

- Both bar chart and line plot are used (`fig2` is correct if both plots are line plots)
- Index is uneven (`idx = range(4)` solves the issue)

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109798/pandas-dataframe-plotting-with-uneven-index-values-creates-skewed-graphs), but this is not the case for me. `df.index` is of class `Int64Index`. Is this an expected behavior or something I should report to the issue tracker?

Comment: pandas bar plots are categorical, hence the bars are always at positions 0,1,... N-1.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That explains the problem and the xtick labels being rotated, thanks. Is it impossible to make it numerical? DataFrames in my actual case have many columns to plot as bar charts, so pandas solution/workaround is very much appreciated (I myself try to find a way as well).

Comment: Yes, use a matplotlib chart instead. `ax.bar(...)` and `ax.plot(...)`