# Convert str to float in Dataframe or Array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (can convert it to numpy array if it's better) like this:

[image: X_train]

And I would like to convert each value from strings to numeric

I have tried to use things like `convert objects` but it doesn't work at all. I think the problem are the square brackets so the function would work If i can get rid of them.

Greetings and thanks in advance

Edit:

Here is where the data comes from

```
X_ans=[]
Y_ans=[]
for i in range (len(data["Births"])-2):
    X=list(data["Births"])[i:i+3]
    Y=list(data["Births"])[i+1]
    X_ans.append(X)
    Y_ans.append(Y)
    in_=pd.DataFrame([ str(x) for x in X_ans ],columns=['input'])
    out=pd.DataFrame([ str(x) for x in Y_ans ],columns=['output'])
ans_1=pd.concat([in_,out],axis=1)
```

ans_1 would be like that:

[image]

Now I split it:

```
msk = np.random.rand(len(ans_1)) < 0.8
traindf = ans_1[msk]
evaldf = ans_1[~msk]
```

And split the values which are separated by commas to get the dimensions

```
    X_train = traindf.iloc[:, 0]
    Y_train = traindf.iloc[:, 1]
    X_test = evaldf.iloc[:, 0]
    Y_test = evaldf.iloc[:, 1]
    X_train = X_train.str.split(pat = ',', expand = True)
    X_train = X_train.values
    X_test = X_test.str.split(pat = ',', expand = True)
    X_test = X_test.values
```

PS:I can use values:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting strings to floats in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729483/converting-strings-to-floats-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: Can you give us a line of code that instantiates that dataframe? It's easier to work with than a picture.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? I'd suggest getting rid of those brackets as early as possible or at least before generating the dataframe in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = df.replace(r'\[|\]','',regex=True).astype(float)
```

for array use:

```
arr = df.values
```

Comment: I think you need '\[|\]'

Comment: @MohamedThasinah there should be `\\` before special characters in regex.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - yeah In my comment i put single slash, but SO treats that as escape character :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({0:['[3242','232','243214]'],1:['[3242','232','243214]']})
```

df:

```
        0        1
0    [3242    [3242
1      232      232
2  243214]  243214]
```

If you want to generalize the logic to remove all non-numeric characters,

```
df.replace(regex=r'\D',value='',inplace=True)
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Output:

```
        0       1
0    3242    3242
1     232     232
2  243214  243214
```