# Could not convert string to float (Pandas)

Tags: python, csv

I would like to read rows of data from .csv file and whenever i run my code it pops out this error. I have no idea how to solve this problem. I've looked up to some similar posts but still cant be solved.

Here is my code:

```
def getThreshold(dataSet, Attributes, isNumeric):
    '''
        Calculates median threshold from train dataset
    '''
    thresholds = []
    for x in Attributes:
        indx = Attributes.index(x)
        numeric = isNumeric[indx]
        if numeric:
            listAtt = []
            for row in dataSet:
                listAtt.append(float(row[indx]))     
            # calculate median a numeric attribute column
            median = statistics.median(listAtt)
            thresholds.append(median)
    return thresholds
```

Here is my sample data, (without quotes)

```
41,management,single,secondary,no,764,no,no,cellular,12,jun,230,2,-1,0,unknown,no
39,blue-collar,married,secondary,no,49,yes,no,cellular,14,may,566,1,370,2,failure,no
60,retired,married,primary,no,0,no,no,telephone,30,jul,130,3,-1,0,unknown,no
31,entrepreneur,single,tertiary,no,247,yes,yes,unknown,2,jun,273,1,-1,0,unknown,no
```

The problem is found in the first column which is the age, are identified as string. Is it the problem in csv file or code?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Casting variables to float can raise a ValueError if it's not possible. Changed your code to check for that.

```
def getThreshold(dataSet, Attributes, isNumeric):
    '''
        Calculates median threshold from train dataset
    '''
    thresholds = []
    for x in Attributes:
        indx = Attributes.index(x)
        numeric = isNumeric[indx]
        if numeric:
            listAtt = []
            for row in dataSet:
                value = row[indx]
                # Try to convert value to float, if it fails then it keeps the original type
                try:
                    value = float(value)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
                listAtt.append(value)
            # calculate median a numeric attribute column
            median = statistics.median(listAtt)
            thresholds.append(median)
    return thresholds
```

*As a side note:
All variables should start with lower-case.
Only class definitions should start with upper-case.*

Comment: I have identified the error. The first column of the data is identified as a string. May I know how to solve it? Is it the problem in code or in the .csv file?

Comment: If you are using pandas dataframe then you can convert the type easily, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729483/converting-strings-to-floats-in-a-dataframe. You should also try to not iterate a dataframe, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas. Basically I recommend trying to rewrite it so you get a dataframe directly from reading the csv file, then use the built-in methods from panda to get medians and such.

Comment: the only problem i'm having now is that the first column is recognized as a string instead of numeric, there are no problems for numeric in other columns. I tried changing the format of columns in excel but changes made cant be saved. May I know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try `pd.Series.astype(float)` or `pd.to_numeric` as the links I posted explained?

Comment: I've tried but still the same. I'm getting \ufeff43 instead of number 43

Comment: Ok i might have solved the issue by saving my .csv file as normal csv instead of with encoding UTF-8. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Oh okay awesome, yeah I just found the same thing, seems to be encoding issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912307/u-ufeff-in-python-string You're welcome! Glad I could help