# Comparing dataframes in Python to calculate difference

Tags: python

I am scraping this website (https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1) using Pandas df. I want to get a snapshot of the coins and price and then get another snapshot of the coins and price 10 seconds later to see whether a coin has moved at price. Here is the code that I am using to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1"
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df).drop(["Unnamed: 0", "Unnamed: 1"], axis=1)
# print(df.head)
df_first = df[['Coin', 'Price']]
time.sleep(10)

url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1"
df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df).drop(["Unnamed: 0", "Unnamed: 1"], axis=1)
df_last = df[['Coin', 'Price']]


df_merged = df_first.merge(df_last, left_on=['Coin'], right_on=['Coin'])
df_merged.set_index(['Coin'], inplace=True)
df_merged['pct_change'] = df_merged[['Price_x','Price_y']].pct_change(axis=1)['Price_y']
df_merged['greater_than_1'] = df_merged['pct_change'] > 10.00
print(df_merged)
```

When I run the code I am getting the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

not sure why. Any help welcome

Comment: Please post *full* stack trace of error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting strings to floats in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729483/converting-strings-to-floats-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `Price` is a string column. You can check dtypes using the [`df.info()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) method.

You need to convert the string '$1,234.5' to float. You can do this by using the  [`converters`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) argument:

```
def parse_price(x):
    return float(x.replace('$', '').replace(',', ''))

url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added?page=1"
converters = {"Price": parse_price}

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4", converters=converters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to divide two strings. Obviously no language will like that!

if you converted both to a float then it'd work. See here for converting columns:

https://datatofish.com/convert-string-to-float-dataframe/

```
df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].astype(float)
```

But - looking at your problem - are you **really** sure this is the way you want to go about looking at price deltas? Would you not look at using one of the apis for an existing server, Binance for instance, and using their ticker streams?