# Why can't I convert dataframe column to float

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert dataframe column to a list of floats without success.

My original code is as below and this is a [Link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9b5be6c8eaa24343179c5312cffc8f1f20220628154942/eb16d2)  to the excel workbook I am working on.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/radoy/Programming/ML Chart Patterns/xx_combined.csv')
df['opens'].astype(float)
```

```
df.dtypes
periods           int64
opens            object
highs            object
lows             object
closes           object
volumes           int64
consolidating    object
dtype: object
```

I keep getting an error:

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[63.240001**

I have gone through the suggestions on another post here but none of them seem to work either.

[Converting strings to floats in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729483/converting-strings-to-floats-in-a-dataframe)

What am I doing wrong? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't directly turn a list into a float

Comment: It looks like you have some bad data; that's all I can say without seeing it myself, and I'm not going to access a site I've never heard of (wetransfer.com) to do that. You need to provide the data *in the question itself*, not an external link. See [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). Please also provide the expected output for completeness. And it wouldn't hurt to include the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should select numbers (with dots) from the strings in your data.

```
import re

pattern = r"[\d.]+"
df['opens'] = df['opens'].apply(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x)[0]).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np


df['opens'] = (
    df['opens']
    .str.strip('[')
    .str.strip(']')
    .str.strip(' ')
    .str.replace(', ', ',')
    .str.split(',')
    .apply(np.array, dtype=float)
)
```

The error you're getting (`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[[63.240001`) is due to the fact that the values from the column `opens` are being read as strings, instead of lists of values.

For example, the first value of `opens` being read is:

```py
"[63.2400016784668, 62.20000076293945, 61.91999816894531, 61.40000152587891, 60.65999984741211, 60.04000091552734, 61.27999877929688, 60.0, 59.11999893188477, 57.88000106811523, 57.7599983215332, 59.04000091552734, 58.18000030517578, 55.29999923706055, 54.13999938964844, 54.52000045776367, 54.13999938964844, 56.72000122070312, 57.0, 58.29999923706055, 58.34000015258789, 58.04000091552734, 58.5, 58.45999908447266, 58.34000015258789, 56.09999847412109, 56.72000122070312, 58.5, 59.13999938964844, 58.41999816894531, 58.65999984741211, 57.90000152587891, 56.43999862670898, 55.7599983215332, 56.27999877929688, 55.22000122070312, 56.5, 56.58000183105469, 56.72000122070312, 56.38000106811523, 55.72000122070312, 55.88000106811523, 56.7400016784668, 58.06000137329102, 58.79999923706055, 59.40000152587891, 59.56000137329102, 58.18000030517578, 58.11999893188477, 57.72000122070312, 57.79999923706055, 56.88000106811523, 57.31999969482422, 56.11999893188477, 56.59999847412109, 56.38000106811523, 57.15999984741211, 56.08000183105469, 56.93999862670898, 57.86000061035156, 57.88000106811523, 58.54000091552734, 58.70000076293945, 57.81999969482422, 58.68000030517578, 58.58000183105469]"
```

instead of something like:

```py
['63.2400016784668',
 '62.20000076293945',
 '61.91999816894531',
 '61.40000152587891',
 '60.65999984741211',
 '60.04000091552734',
 '61.27999877929688',
 '60.0',
 '59.11999893188477',
 '57.88000106811523',
 '57.7599983215332',
 '59.04000091552734',
 '58.18000030517578',
 '55.29999923706055',
 '54.13999938964844',
 '54.52000045776367',
 '54.13999938964844',
 '56.72000122070312',
 '57.0',
 '58.29999923706055',
 '58.34000015258789',
 '58.04000091552734',
 '58.5',
 '58.45999908447266',
 '58.34000015258789',
 '56.09999847412109',
 '56.72000122070312',
 '58.5',
 '59.13999938964844',
 '58.41999816894531',
 '58.65999984741211',
 '57.90000152587891',
 '56.43999862670898',
 '55.7599983215332',
 '56.27999877929688',
 '55.22000122070312',
 '56.5',
 '56.58000183105469',
 '56.72000122070312',
 '56.38000106811523',
 '55.72000122070312',
 '55.88000106811523',
 '56.7400016784668',
 '58.06000137329102',
 '58.79999923706055',
 '59.40000152587891',
 '59.56000137329102',
 '58.18000030517578',
 '58.11999893188477',
 '57.72000122070312',
 '57.79999923706055',
 '56.88000106811523',
 '57.31999969482422',
 '56.11999893188477',
 '56.59999847412109',
 '56.38000106811523',
 '57.15999984741211',
 '56.08000183105469',
 '56.93999862670898',
 '57.86000061035156',
 '57.88000106811523',
 '58.54000091552734',
 '58.70000076293945',
 '57.81999969482422',
 '58.68000030517578',
 '58.58000183105469']
```

Answer (score -1):

there are some some non digit characters like space etc. you can try to replace them all with null prior to converting to float

```
df['open'].replace(r'(\"|\[|\s)',"", regex=True).astype('float')
```

```
0     63.240002
1     12.600000
2    213.149994
3     11.280000
4     76.820000
5     15.600000
6    210.179993
Name: opens, dtype: float64
```

Test Data from provided Excel

```
periods opens
65  [63.2400016784668"
29  [12.60000038146973
19  [213.1499938964844
44  [11.27999973297119
78  [76.81999969482422
34  [15.60000038146973
74  [210.1799926757812
```

Comment: @Dodo,  one line solution, that is vectorized. Does it work for you?